How to efficiently FOR-loop over a huge SELECT result set in PL/pgSQL
In a PL/pgSQL stored procedure, I would like to calculate multiple averages (simple, weighted, etc) over different periods of time and over different number of data points, all in a single loop.
Therefore, I cannot set the LIMIT boundary for the SELECT that the loop loops over - because the biggest time period can still have not enough data points, so I can't put LIMIT 1000 nor can I do WHERE date_created >= (one year ago).
Thus I would like not to limit the SELECT query in any way, and instead loop through it until I'm done and have calculated all the averages that I needed over all possible chunks of data (either time or quantity based), and then I just call EXIT to stop the looping.
My concern is, what if, without LIMIT or WHERE constrains, the SELECT returns 100 million rows while I only end up needing first 10k of them - will my stored PL/pgSQL procedure actually run the huge 100 million row selection and then loop over it, or will it loop only as needed?
I do understand that the FOR loop uses cursors internally. But my question is about the result set that needs to be built before a cursor can loop through it. So, is it a bad idea to run a FOR loop over a SELECT query with no LIMIT/WHERE constrains that could potentially return 100M rows, and then EXIT as needed? Or should I just process data in chunks of ~1k items?
The SELECT statement looks backwards starting from some point in time, and that is why it has:

where date_created < START_TIME
order by date_created desc


When cursor is not hold, then "usually" it is not materialized - depends on used internal operations. So although you process huge set of rows, the memory usage can be low. And although the cursor is materialized, then the memory usage for materialization should be limited by work_mem configuration value. After crossing this limit, the data are stored to temp file.

Could you please explain the meaning of "When cursor is not hold"? How do I make sure it is not hold?

Hold cursor is created by command DECLARE CURSOR HOLD FOR .... In this case, the cursor lifetime is not limited by transaction - cursor is fully materialized (all rows are processed and stored to memory (up to work_mem) or temp file). PL/pgSQL FOR command doesn't use holdable cursors.

After thinking about it for a while, I guess my concern is that the way I understand it, is that because there is some ordering and filtering in the SELECT, the database will have to create the resultset first, and loop over it later; so I was thinking about what happens if the resultset is huge, like millions of rows, and how to avoid this "find first, then loop over it".

when you use index over date_created then all work is just one index scan. It is like reading from phone list. Very easy and effective for database.
